# Firebase, how to redirect after login?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Im learning how to use Firebase for a college project, but my knowledge of JS is low, and Im having problems with a thing. What I want is that after the login is correct the user should be redirected to X site but I have no idea how to do it. This is what I currently have:

```
const inputEmail = document.getElementById('inputEmail');
const inputPassword = document.getElementById('inputPassword');
const btnIniciarSesion = document.getElementById('btnIniciarSesion');

btnIniciarSesion.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const email =  inputEmail.value;
    const password = inputPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
});
```

Any advise of how to do that?

Comment: i can explain this in java, is ok for you ?

Comment: because to do this you will need to do it with an AuthListener, with this you can get when firebase.auth != null you can do an intent and go to the X place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(user => {
        // Sign in success
        // Route to site here
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    })
```

Comment: Thanks Eric! Worked perfectly, now my login form redirects when the login is successful :)